# View blockchain blocks in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am developing a hyperledger fabric client application. I have set up the default hyperledger fabric network using [IBM blockchain platform vs code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform). I am able to view the world state in couch db in the web interface. How do I view all the transactions stored in the blocks of the blockchain? I am using a windows 10 machine. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the literal transactions should be much less interesting than, the world state.  You'll find the initial proposal and parameters, a read/write set, any chaincode event, and then a lot of assorted certificates, signatures, and other boilerplate that isn't terribly interesting for most users.

That being said, if you retrieve a block (either using QSCC, or better yet the Deliver service such as via [`peer channel fetch`](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchannel.html#peer-channel-fetch)) you can decode the block to JSON using the [`configtxlator tool`](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/configtxlator.html).  Although the original, and most common use for this tool is inspecting config blocks, it should work just fine on normal blocks as well.

You can decode a block using the command:

```
configtxlator proto_decode --type common.Block --input <your_input_block>
```

If you want to do this decoding from inside an application, `configtxlator` can also operate as a REST server and you can see examples of how to invoke it using curl in the documentation.